# react-router-dom NavLink Item is not active

Tags: reactjs

i have a reactJs project. the navlink isActive is true when i click on the item.  i have two navlinks Users and Attorneys. if user click on Users then Users is active.  onn that page we have a list of users whenn i click on user 1 its open a new tab where. where the users NavItem is not active.

what i have tried is this

```
// Component with NavLink and localStorage handling
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navigation = () => {
  const [activeNavLink, setActiveNavLink] = useState(null); // State to manage active NavLink

  // Function to handle NavLink click
  const handleNavLinkClick = (navLinkKey) => {
    // Store the active state in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('activeNavLink', navLinkKey);
    setActiveNavLink(navLinkKey); // Update active state in component state
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Retrieve active state from localStorage on component mount
    const storedActiveNavLink = localStorage.getItem('activeNavLink');
    setActiveNavLink(storedActiveNavLink); // Set active state in component state
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <NavLink
        to="/home"
        onClick={() => handleNavLinkClick('/home')}
        className={activeNavLink === '/home' ? 'active' : ''}
      >
        Home
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink
        to="/about"
        onClick={() => handleNavLinkClick('/about')}
        className={activeNavLink === '/about' ? 'active' : ''}
      >
        About
      </NavLink>
      {/* Add more NavLinks as needed */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: can you `console.log` to see the activeNavLink value from the new tap? Also `to` route is correct

Comment: React Router's NavLink components will handle active state for you so you don't need to use state and local storage. The `active` class is applied automatically.

Comment: @HenryWoody there is an issue. NavLink has a state of. isActive but when I click in link that open on new Windows the isActive is false. for example I have a NavLink users but when I click a specific user that is opened in a  new tab .  the user NavLinks in not active on that new window

Comment: Do you set localStorage from the links to individual user pages?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using state to check whether it is active or not use pathname. For example:

```
   <NavLink
    to="/home"
    onClick={() => handleNavLinkClick('/home')}
    className={window.location.pathanme === '/home' ? 'active' : ''}
  >
    Home
  </NavLink>
```

State refreshes when you reload the page or go in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NavLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const navItems = [
    { to: '/', label: 'Home' },
    { to: '/users', label: 'Users' },
    { to: '/posts', label: 'Posts' },
    { to: '/albums', label: 'Albums' },
];

const Nav = () => {
    const location = useLocation();

    return (
        <div>
            {navItems.map((item) => (
                <NavLink
                    key={item.label}
                    to={item.to}
                    className={location.pathname === item.to ? 'active' : ''}
                >
                    {item.label}
                </NavLink>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Nav;
```

Comment: on users I have. a list of users when I. open it in a new tab the users tab is. not active

Comment: Provide more code to see what exactly happens.
I think that because you have a new path like users/user_id, that means you are not in the path users anymore.

Answer (score -1):

When you use NavLink states is changing so just use 'preventDefault'.

```html
  <NavLink
    to="/home"
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      handleNavLinkClick('/home')
    }}
    className={activeNavLink === '/home' ? 'active' : ''}
  >
    Home
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can solve this easier:

```
  const location = useLocation();


  <NavLink
    to="/home"
    className={location.pathname.includes("home") ? 'active' : ''}
  >
    Home
  </NavLink>
```